# Junit5 test is failed with mutableStateOf and coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, junit5, coroutine

I have a ViewModel class:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: Repo,
) : ViewModel() {

    val id = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())

    fun init(token: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                id.value = TextFieldValue(repo.getId(token))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I want to write a test code for the `init` function.

Below is my test code:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class, CoroutinesTestExtension::class)
class MyViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var coroutineScope = CoroutinesTestExtension()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repo: Repo

    private lateinit var vm: MyViewModel


    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)

        vm = MyViewModel(repo)
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("init() test")
    inner class InitTest {

        private val token = "test-token"

        @Test
        fun initTest() = runTest {
            val id = "test-id"
            `when`(repo.getId(token))
                .thenReturn(id)

            vm.init(token)
            advanceUntilIdle()

            assertEquals(id, vm.id.value.text)
        }
    }
```

If I run this test code, it fails with the below message:

```
expected:<[test-id]> but was:<[]>
Expected :test-id
Actual   :
```

I found some things...

First, If I remove the line `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`, the test pass!
But `repo.getId(token)` should be run on the Background thread.

Second, If I change the type of `id` from `MutableStateOf` to `MutableLiveData`, it works fine.
But the `id` is using on the `View/Fragment` like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyTextInput() {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = viewModel.id.value,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.id.value = it },
    )
}
```

So I couldn't change it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary  TextFieldValue into ViewModel

you can change to string and test it.

ViewModel

```
val id = mutableStateOf("")
fun init(token: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                id.value = repo.getId(token)
            }
        }
    }
```

test

```
@Test
    fun success() = coroutineRule.runBlockingTest {

        val token = "token"
        val id = "test-id"
        //Given
        coEvery { repo.getId(token) } returns "test-id" 

        vm.init(token)

        assertEquals(id, vm.id )
    }
```

Comment: what is the `coroutineRule` ??